# How do I create a Public API key on the Google Developer Console?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to set up Google+ Authentication by following these instructions: https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

I've activated the Google+ API within my project on the Google Developers Console, but when I click Credentials in the side bar, the "Create new Key" button is grayed out. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Edit: On a possibly related note, clicking "Create new Client ID" only includes an option for "Installed application" and not "web application" or "service account". Do I need to add another API to have these options enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that would grey out your public API button, but I do know that you won't have "web app" or "service account" enabled if you didn't fill the Consent Screen.

Try going into "Your project -> APIs & auth -> Consent screen" and fill the information there. I have never seen the buttons greyed out, but I know you can't generate a lot of the keys without the Consent Screen filled up.

Comment: I ended up creating a new app and the problem went away, not really sure what happened there...